# Adapting motion controls to changes in the player's orientation

Tags: ios, movement, mobile, user-experience, controllers

I am using **gyroscope data** (pitch, roll) to **move the player's space ship**.

It works perfectly as long as you play in a standard position (e.g. sitting down).

Once you start using it lying down (e.g. in the bed), the control does not work anymore as the pitch and roll values I used become too big.

Here is the code I use, written in Objective-C. Any idea on how to improve/fix this?

```
-(void) gyroUpdate:(ccTime) delta
{
    CMAttitude * attitude;
    CMDeviceMotion * motion = [GameController sharedGameController].motionManager.deviceMotion;
    attitude = motion.attitude;

    float pitch =  attitude.pitch;
    float roll =  attitude.roll;

    ShooterScene * shooterScene = (ShooterScene *) [self parent];
    ShipEntity *playerSprite = [shooterScene playerShip];

    const float roolSpeed = 1000.0f;
    const float pitchSpeed = 1000.0f;

    //Midpoint of pitch is 0.5f, here the Player ship is NOT supposed to move.
    //Moving "forward" is equal to values towards 0.0f-
    //Moving "backwards" is equal to values towards 1.0f+


    float pitchProgression = 0.5f - pitch;

     CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(playerSprite.position.x + roll * delta * roolSpeed, playerSprite.position.y   + delta * pitchSpeed * pitchProgression );

    [playerSprite setPosition:newPosition];
}
```

Comment: use a base position (customizable in settings) and use values relative to that

Comment: ...yep, I thought about that. I would like to have a dynamic beheaviour change. Pheraps I could set some tresholds gyroscope values after which the base position changes. The only thing is that it will not be very sensitive. In a way I would need a function that returns a progressive base position change. With my question I was hoping that there is already a canonical function / solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

I solved a [similar problem once with the Wii remote](http://www.nintendoworldreport.com/devjournal/23762) - but we didn't have the gyroscopes & magnetometers common in mobile devices today (the Wii Motion Plus was just coming out at the time), just accelerometer. Here's a modified version of the approach...

1. Keep track of a reference frame - say, a current "up" and "right" vector, or a quaternion. Initialize it to something like an identity matrix.
2. Estimate how still the device is being held - by checking whether total acceleration is close to 1G for instance, or that all gyroscope axes are reporting close to zero.
3. Use this estimate to gradually increase or (more sharply) decrease a "learning factor" - a coefficient that's zero when the player is moving and approaches 1 when they've been still for a period of time.
4. Blend your reference frame toward the current "up" and "right" vectors or quaternion reported by the device's sensors, at a slow rate proportionate to your learning factor. (So when the learning factor is small during movement, you remain locked in your old coordinate system)
5. When reading motion data, transform it into your reference frame, and do all your gameplay calculations in that frame.

So now if the player holds the device on its side, they'll steer sharply to one side for a few seconds, but then the control input will gradually neutralize as they keep the new position, and input will be relative to this new position from then on.

Note that depending on the device, you might not have the ability to discern all axes of movement. For instance, if your device lacks a magnetometer, you won't have an absolute measure of yaw. If the player lays down sideways, what was formerly an axis you could measure absolutely (pitch) becomes one you can't (yaw), and you may get some drift. Working with relative values may help, or you can fake one axis of sensor input to keep it from drifting too far.

Comment: Hi, I am really interested in this answer but am a little bit confused with why you would use an identity matrix, do you have any examples in code of this process? I would love to learn more

Comment: @GerardSimpson As described, it's just used to initialize the orientation guesstimate. At startup, we often have no idea how we're oriented initially, so the identity matrix is as good a first / a-priori guess as anything else, until we get our first frame of orientation data and can start updating our estimate.